# How can I assign a function to <span>? To display a number in a span

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I assign a function to ? To display a number in a span
[Screуnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/039tn.jpg)
Please tell me how can I do this?
Created with React Js

```html
function onlineCount() {
  Math.floor(100+480*Math.random()); 
}

setInterval(onlineCount, 1000);

function HeaderTop() {
  
  // const onlineCount = Math.floor(100+480*Math.random()) 

  return (
    <div className="header-top">
        <div className="header-social">
        <div className="header-online">
          <div className="online-general-bar">
            <div className="online-bar"></div>
          </div>
          <span>{() => onlineCount}</span>
```

Comment: Post code as text, not as screenshot. Also you do not call the function. And the function does not return anything, it just logs stuff.

Comment: `function onlineCount() {
  return Math.floor(100+480*Math.random()); 
}` U can try this.

Comment: How can I put this function on the span?

Answer (score -1):

REACT

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root')
);

function tick() {
  const element = (
    <span>{Math.floor(100 + 480 * Math.random());
            setTimeout(function () { onlineCount(); }, 1000);}
    </span>
  );
  root.render(element);
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

PURE JAVASCRIPT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onlineCount() {
            document.getElementById("mySpan").innerText = Math.floor(100 + 480 * Math.random());
            setTimeout(function () { onlineCount(); }, 1000);
        }
        setTimeout(function () { onlineCount(); }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <div>
            <span id="mySpan"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its React JS. How can I do this in react js?

Comment: I suggest you follow the tutorials here, which show how to reference functions from within elements. https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html